# An interesting problem on springs

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring

If I place two identical objects of mass $m$ at either end of a spring with spring constant $k$ and the whole system is placed on a horizontal frictionless surface, then what is the frequency of oscillation?

This is NOT a homework problem. And let me show my work which does yield the incorrect answer, but is not rigorous. The problem boils down to finding the effective spring constant.

By imagining we cut the spring in half and attach a small mass in the center, we know that the effective force constant is $2k+2k=4k$ (each half spring has constant $2k$). Apparenty the effective force constant is $2k$.

I have a lot of trouble with these problems involving combined springs, and it is a very tricky concept.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is not far off. Problems like these are best answered in the center of mass frame.

Let's assume that the spring has length $2\ell$. Now put two systems side by side. System A is the one you described: mass $m$, spring of length $2\ell$ and spring constant $k$, and another mass $m$. System B looks like system A - but you notice that there is only one mass, a spring of length $\ell$ and a mirror (in which you see a reflection of the spring and the mass).

The two systems look identical. But you know how to solve system B: it's a spring that's half the length, but still with mass $m$. For a displacement $\Delta x$ the force increases by $2k\Delta x$ (since the spring is half as long), and the mass that moves is $m$. It follows that the equation of motion is

$$m\ddot x = -2k x$$

and the resonant frequency is given by

$$\omega = \sqrt{\frac{2k}{m}}$$

Note that if the two masses are not equal, you can do something similar (but without mirrors) by imagining the point on the spring that will not move when the two masses are pulled towards each other. If there are no external forces acting, the point that is stationary is the center of mass (since it moves in response to external forces, and they are not there). The center of mass is in the middle when the masses are equal - when they are not, it will move towards the heavier end. In general, for a spring length $\ell$ the center of mass will be distance $x$ from mass $m$ and $\ell - x$ from $M$ such that

$$x = \frac{M}{m+M}\ell$$

Again, when $m=M$ that means the center of mass is in the middle and the frequency increases by $\sqrt{2}$. I will leave it as an exercise for you to calculate the resonant frequency for the general case of unequal masses.

**UPDATE**
Some more derivation:

[image]

The center of mass in the above diagram will be at a distance $x$ from mass $m$ such that

$$m\cdot x = M\cdot(\ell - x)\\
x = \frac{M}{m+M}\ell$$

We will work in the center of mass frame of the system (which is moving at constant velocity when there are no external forces acting on it - so the center of mass frame is an inertial frame of reference and our equations of motion should work "normally").

Focusing just on mass $m$, the spring that appears to act on it has length $x$ (the center of mass is stationary, so if we imagine that point attached to a wall everything to the left of that wall will look exactly the same).  If the spring of length $\ell$ has spring constant $k$, then a shorter spring of length $x<\ell$ has spring constant $k' = k\frac{\ell}{x}$.

The resonant frequency of the mass $m$ is then

$$\begin{align}\omega &= \sqrt{\frac{k'}{m}}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{k\ell}{xm}}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{k(m+M)}{mM}}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{k}{m'}}\\
\end{align}$$

Where

$$m' = \frac{mM}{M+m}$$

Sometimes we call $m'$ the *reduced* mass (sometimes written as $\mu$). It is a convenient quantity for a system like this because it describes the behavior of the system in the center of mass frame. Note that we would have arrived at exactly the same expression if we had started from the other side, since the equation is symmetrical - and of course in resonance the motion of the two masses must be equal and opposite, so they need to have the same resonant frequency. This gives some confidence that the center of mass approach is a good one - the result we obtain is sensible.

When $m=M$ you can see that this equation reduces to the one that I derived earlier.

Comment: I understand your explanation. But I will need some help with the general case.  First, how do you know there is a stationary point in the first place? In fact, why does there have to be a stationary point in the original scenario: what if you stretch the spring by pulling on just one of the masses - then the whole system moves.... I would really appreciate your help since I need to master these tricky problems.

Comment: I explicitly said I am working in the center of mass frame of reference: when there is no _external_ force on the _system_ of the masses plus spring, there is no _acceleration_ of the center of mass so there exists an _inertial_ (non accelerating) frame of reference in which the c.o.m. is stationary. That is the reference frame I use. Laws of physics work in all inertial frames, so I get to pick the one that makes the math easier.

Comment: yes but you say "point that does not move". even after you have pulled the mass at one end, and let go, the whole system moves.

Comment: Yes, the whole system moves... and **so does my frame of reference**. In the frame of reference the center of mass _doesn't_ move, because that's how I _define_ it.

Comment: Oh ok i didnt realize the origin was at the center of mass. Ok but then why does it look symmetrical if you stand at the center of mass. Its not obvious to me.

Comment: The middle of the spring moves half as far as the mass you moved (in the lab frame). If you move with the middle (i.e. In the c.o.m. frame), the motion of the stationary mass appears as minus the motion of the mass you moved. And the force on one is minus the force on the other (Newton 3) so they accelerate in opposite directions.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could edit your answer to prove the general case since this is still confusing to me. These are the only kinds of mechanics problems which give me trouble...

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou see my most recent edit. Do you get it now?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume inertial resonance. When one end of the spring (or one mass) is displaced from its equilibrium by $x$ distance, so is the other side, but in the opposite direction (obviously). This mean that the spring is effectively stretched by $2x$. So at the moment one side of the spring is stretched by $x$, the effective force on the mass at that side will be $-k(2x)$, as well as on the other side.

$$-k(2x)=-(2k)x \implies \nu = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sqrt{ \frac{2k}{m}}=\sqrt{2} \nu_0$$

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. The thing that confuses me is that the whole system moves onece you displace one side. Is this rigorous?

Comment: I assumed **inertial** resonance - that it was symmetrically oscillating in an inertial reference frame. In that case I suppose what I wrote would be rigorous enough if you just wrote down that you're considering the center-of-mass reference frame.

Comment: I'm a chump though, so maybe you should wait for somebody else to answer.